# Using Special Characters In Python

Tags: python, string, character

I am writing a program using Python 2.7 and Tkinter, and at one point I need to display variable symbols on my GUI. I've decided to use the Label object, but I need to display symbols such as alpha, beta, ohm, and pi. I don't know how to type them out, let alone make them appear in python. Here's an example of my code:

```
pilabeltext = StringVar()
pilabeltext.set("This is where I want the Pi symbol")
pilabel = Label(app,text=pilabeltext)
pilabel.pack()
```

I'd also like to be able to let characters in strings have subscripts and superscripts, so if I wanted to write alpha subscript 1 and alpha subscript 2, or alpha squared, how could I do that?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: AFAIK, you can't use subscripts and superscripts in a Tkinter `Label`, but can work around this using a `Text` widget and use the tag option `offset`.

Answer (score 7):

Ensure your script is UTF-8 encoded, then you should have no problems

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

w = Label(root, text="Hello, pi -> π !")
w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

For using subscripts etc, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953697/how-to-use-subscripts-in-tkinter-label):

[image]