# How to use subscripts in Tkinter Label?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I use subscripts in a Tkinter Label?

I found a lot of posts like [this](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/169455/superscript-in-a-tkinter-label), but that does not help me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For rich formatting, use a small text widget rather than a label. You then have the ability to add all kinds of formatting to the information. You can, for example, use the `offset` attribute on a text tag to create superscripts and subscripts.

Just set state to `disabled` after configuring the widget, and for all intents and purposes it will look like a label. The main difference is that you have to manually set the size since a text widget won't expand to fit its contents like a label does.

For example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        l = tk.Text(self, width=5, height=2, borderwidth=0, 
                    background=self.cget("background"))
        l.tag_configure("subscript", offset=-4)
        l.insert("insert", "H", "", "2", "subscript", "O")
        l.configure(state="disabled")
        l.pack(side="top")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just need a few subscripts (e.g. for an equation), it may be simpler to use unicode subscript characters.

```
import Tkinter as Tk
root = Tk.Tk()
Tk.Label(root, text=u'% Change = (y\u1d62-y\u2080)/y\u2080 \u00d7100').pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: is there a reference to these subscript characters? or better a python function that - given a string - converts it to corresponding subscript characters?

Comment: There are a limited number of available characters: http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf

Comment: This can be also helpful list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)