# Printing subscript in python | X_{some text}

Tags: python, string, subscript

i am looking for a method to print subscripts in python. So far I have only found posts where the subscript contains numbers. Instead I'm looking for a method to write arbitrary text

X_{some random Text}

Does someone know how this can be done?

Edit:
I create a GUI with Tkinter in jupyter Notebook. The GUI should contain texts with subscript

Comment: Write where -- in a console? in a text file? "Subscript" is a *text* attribute, not a special type of characters. You cannot write arbitrary text in subscript, just like you cannot write any text "in italics", or "in Times New Roman Bold at 14 pt". Those numbers you saw were actually [really subscript characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts).

Comment: I have edited my post.

Comment: So basically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953697/how-to-use-subscripts-in-tkinter-label

Answer (score -1):

Unicode has only defined superscript for letter **'n'** and subscript for letters **'a,e,o,x,h,k,l,m,n,p,s,t,symbol(schwa)'** along with a few numbers and symbols link [here](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf).

This code can use alphabets on the superscript and subscript In This code format() is Function and in Format function ('\unicode')
 irrespective of it being on a **Tkinter GUI, Console or STDOUT**.

By using this table [Unicode subscripts and superscripts](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf) you can give suitable Unicode to the suitable one

you can use superscript and subscript and pass the UNICODE for the character you want

```
"A{}".format('\u00B2')  # superscript 2
"B{}".format('\N{LATIN SUBSCRIPT SMALL LETTER X}')  # subscript x
"C{}".format('\N{SUPERSCRIPT LATIN SMALL LETTER N}')  # superscript n
```

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)'s a list of all Unicode Characters

Comment: How can i add more that one character. For example: "B{}".format('\N{LATIN SUBSCRIPT SMALL LETTER X}') this create B_x. How can i get for example B_xdct ?

Comment: There is no such function in python as I'm aware. You can go ahead and write one easily but there is a limitation. Unicode has defined superscript for letter 'n' only and subscript for letters 'a,e,o,x,h,k,l,m,n,p,s,t' along with a few numbers and symbols link [here](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf). There was a proposal back in 2011 [proposal](http://www.unicode.org/L2/L2011/11208-n4068.pdf) for Inclusion of all basic Latin letters A...Z + a...z. Sorry @Miradius but I'm not aware of any other formatting methods to do what you've asked.